# How to get know which button is press ("Edit ", delete)in listview in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile .I just wanted to know which button is press in list view.I have to do three different task on Edit , delete , row click .I need to do like that it will not interfere each other?

here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/MneT6/1/

```
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {




       $('#folderData').append(
            '<li class="caseRowClick" id="' + i + '" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="img/Blue-Folder.png">' + '<h2>' + i  + '</h2>' + '<p>' + i+ '</p>' + '<p>' + i + '</p>' +'<span class="ui-li-count">' + i + '</span>'+  '</a>' +
            '<span class="ctrl togg"><fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" ><button class="edit button_design">Edit</button><button class="del button_design">Delete</button></fieldset><span>' + '</li>'
        );
           $('#folderData').listview('refresh');
           }
```

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE ELEBORATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just attach on click event like this

```
$('#folderData button.edit').on('click',function(e){ 
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert('edit has been clicked in row ' + $(this).closest('li.caseRowClick').attr('id')););
});

$('#folderData button.del').on('click',function(e) { 
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert('delete has been clicked in row ' + $(this).closest('li.caseRowClick').attr('id')); 
});

$('#folderData li.caseRowClick').on('click',function(e) { 
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert('row has been clicked with ID ' + $(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

Comment: and how to know which button is click?

Comment: Different functions for different buttons as you can see from code

Comment: you are not inseted this your fiddle..:(

Comment: actually i want to go different pages on three different things(row , eid, delete). but they don't clash

Comment: if i need to go different pages then i write code below this e.stopPropagation();

Answer (score 0):

You can assign delegated event handlers for the buttons based on their classes. Quick example, your edit button has a class of `edit`, so you can make an event handler such as:

```
$("#folderData").on("click", ".edit", function() {
    alert("Edit was pressed on row: " + $(this).closest("li").attr("id"));
});
```

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MneT6/5/

While this is only the edit button, it should get you on the right path for your other buttons as well.

Comment: so i will add same with delete. but what about row click..?is he interfere ?